# How Install Ubuntu 21.04 (Desktop) on Raspberry Pi 4 using Serial Console?

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, raspberrypi, serial-port

Hello how can I install ubuntu desktop 21.04 on raspberry pi 4 using serial console?

How do I prepare the SD card files to make this happen?

Thanks.

Edit: I was able to fix my problem installing ubuntu 21.04 on the raspberry pi using UART TTL:

For those who understand how Ubuntu works and operate, ubuntu never establishes a default password for the root. I needed to modify the boot files for letting ubuntu communicate via serial UART pin on the raspberry pi and also adding a password hash for the root user.

First I needed to add a password for the root user:

Here is a YouTube video on how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyG1bMk522I

Then I needed to allow UART TTL communication, here is the tutorial on doing that:
https://limesdr.ru/en/2020/10/17/rpi4-headless-ubuntu/

Here is the pic proof I logged into the Ubuntu 21.04 installer as root via UART Serial TTL:

[Logged in as root into the ubuntu 21.04 installer via UART TTL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu3Ea.jpg)

Now I can install ubuntu 21.04... since I have access to the ubuntu installer.

Comment: Install Ubuntu Server 20.04 (download link: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi). See this link for installation instructions: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview. Then install the desktop environment with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. Alternatively, you can install the desktop version of Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is it possible to use the desktop release instead? It's because in the future I'll work on with additional Raspberry Pis and do not want to waste time using the server release and installing the desktop packages via the internet. It would be nice if I can get the serial console working on the desktop release so that i can install the ssh package and now I have a working ubuntu for the pi 4. I read that it is possible to get the serial console working during boot but have to edit the SD card boot partition file but I can not find any documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by serial console?

Comment: Communicating with the Pi using PuTTY serial terminal via a TTL to USB converter hooked with Pi 4's UART pins.